# jquery jcarousel is not always displaying right in IE9

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

It's really weird. The jcarousel by Jan Sorgalla seems to work fine in Chrome but in IE9 the images are sometime stack vertically meaning I can see all of the images at once.
Sometimes when I hit refresh they display normally but other times they continue to show separated in a list where I can see the bullet next to each one.
Here's the code I'm using:

Update: I changed to the actual HTML

```
<ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">

                        <li>

                                        <img id="MainContent_Image1b" src="images/img1.png" style="height:275px;width:825px;" />

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <table style="position: relative">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <img id="MainContent_Image8" src="images/img2.png" />
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <img id="MainContent_Image9" src="Images/btn.png" style="border: 0px none; position: absolute;
                                                top: 205px; left: 25px;" />
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img id="MainContent_Image10" src="images/img3.png" />
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: I wonder if the inline styles and position:absolute may attribute to your problem. However, the code you're showing is not the generated HTML as it it sent to the browser, as it contains <asp tags

Comment: I edited my original post to show the generated html

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I had such problem when I used remote .css and .js files try to copy them to your folder if they are remotely